# Finding partial derivatives to use in Itos rule

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, stochastic-processes

If $X_t, Y_t \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $B^{ n \times n}$ and

$Y_t = B X_t$, where the SDE of $X_t$ has the general form $dX_t = F(X_t) + G dW_t$.

I am trying to find:

1. $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} Y_t$
2. $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} Y_t$
3. $\frac{\partial }{\partial xx} Y_t$

, in order to use in Ito's rule.

$X_t$ could also be shown as $X(t)$ and similarly $Y_t$.

Comment: Well, the answer to you question is: 1. doesn't exists, because $Y_{t}$ is not differnatiable a.s., 2 & 3 is zero, since $Y_{t}$ does not depend on $x$. You lack basic understanding, I'm afraid. No offense. What you need are first and second order partial derivatives of the function $f(x):=Bx$.

Comment: Hi @Tobsn, no offence taken I appreciate any help. That's why I am here I guess.

Comment: In my notation what I mean by $x$ is in fact $x_t$. The reason I used that notation was to simplify it. $Y_t$ does depend on $X_t$ as it's simply a linear transformation of $X_t$.  I could be wrong here so I really appreciate any criticism. @Tobsn

Comment: Sure. $Y_{t}=f(X_{t})$ with the $f$ I defined above.